# Hive - insert into table partition throwing error

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, spark-thriftserver

I am trying to create a partitioned table in Hive on spark and load it with data available in other table in Hive. 
I am getting following error while loading the data:

> Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.ValidationFailureSemanticException:
>   Partition spec {cardsuit=, cardcolor=, cardSuit=SPA, cardColor=BLA}
>   contains non-partition columns;

following are the commands used to execute the task:-

```
create table if not exists hive_tutorial.hive_table(color string, suit string,value string) comment 'first hive table' row format delimited fields terminated by '|' stored as TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'file:///E:/Kapil/software-study/Big_Data_NoSql/hive/deckofcards.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE hive_table; --data is correctly populated(52 rows)

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;

create table if not exists hive_tutorial.hive_table_partitioned(color string, suit string,value int) comment 'first hive table' partitioned by (cardSuit string,cardColor string) row format delimited fields terminated by '|' stored as TEXTFILE;

INSERT INTO TABLE hive_table_partitioned PARTITION (cardSuit,cardColor) select color,suit,value,substr(suit, 1, 3) as cardSuit,substr(color, 1, 3) as cardColor from hive_table;

--alternatively i tried
INSERT OVERWRITE  TABLE hive_table_partitioned PARTITION (cardSuit,cardColor) select color,suit,value,substr(suit, 1, 3) as cardSuit,substr(color, 1, 3) as cardColor from hive_table;
```

sample of data:-

BLACK|SPADE|2

BLACK|SPADE|3

BLACK|SPADE|4

BLACK|SPADE|5

BLACK|SPADE|6

BLACK|SPADE|7

BLACK|SPADE|8

BLACK|SPADE|9

I am using spark 2.2.0 and java version 1.8.0_31.

I have checked and tried answers given in similar thread but could not solve my problem:-
[SemanticException Partition spec {col=null} contains non-partition columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648785/semanticexception-partition-spec-col-null-contains-non-partition-columns)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reading the scripts above while creating tables ,value column is type of int in partitioned table where as string in original. Error was misleading !!!